# nginx for two different server in different folders, only first working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

```
# user www-data;

worker_processes auto;
# pid /run/nginx.pid;
# include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http { 
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;    
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;    
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;    
    # access_log /nginx/logs/access.log;
    # error_log /nginx/logs/error.log;    
    gzip on;    
    # include /nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    proxy_cache_path /nginx/files levels=1:2 keys_zone=assets:48m max_size=20g inactive=2h;
    proxy_cache_path /nginx/server2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=assetsserver2:48m max_size=20g inactive=2h;

    upstream backend {
        server 192.168.1.4:30121;
    }

    upstream backendserver2 {
        server 192.168.1.4:30120;
    }

    server {
        listen 32888;

        server_name 192.168.1.22;

        access_log /nginx/logs/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /nginx/logs/reverse-error.log;

        location /files/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend$request_uri;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache assets;
            proxy_cache_valid 1y;
            proxy_cache_key $request_uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        }

        location /server2/ {
            proxy_pass http://backendserver2$request_uri;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache assetsserver2;
            proxy_cache_valid 1y;
            proxy_cache_key $request_uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to make nginx work on two FiveM servers, but only the one in the /file/ folder is working, the cache the other one that I tried to put in another folder doesn't work, I've tried everything but without success.

I tried to search in several places and in several ways, but only the first server works, the second always gives an error when I try to enter the server.